# Vue 3 – <Transition> renders non-element root node that cannot be animated

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

App.vue has a `transition` tag to fade the pages out and in.

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
   <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
      <component :is="Component"></component>
   </transition>
</router-view>
```

The Page.vue file has a simple  structure, however, it also has a basic *sliderjs* component which throws the error `<Transition> renders non-element root node that cannot be animated.` If the `transition` tag is removed, everything works fine.

```html
<div v-if="page.isReady">
   <swiper>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
   </swiper>
</div>
```

https://swiperjs.com/vue/

The file also has the following:

```js
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
    
export default {
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
 
  setup () {
    return {
      page: usePage()
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any trick to fix the error? Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

No.

```html
<template>
  <div></div>
  <div>~someone~</div>
</template>
```

Yes.

```html
<template>
  <div>
  　　<div></div>
    ~someone~
  </div>
</template>
```

If you do not use a "div" tag just inside the "Template" tag, you will get the same error. (By the way, it was possible to use other than div tags)

Comment: This resolved my issue with Vuetify transitions

Answer (score 41):

Transitions require single children nodes. Therefore you can wrap the `<component>` tag inside a `<div>`, however, a plain `<div>` inside a `<transition>` won't trigger the transition, but changing the `key` attribute does.

We can obtain a unique key by getting the route name:

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <div :key="route.name">  
      <component :is="Component"></component>
    </div>
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

This will effectively transition between routes with a different name, but if you also want to transition between routes of the same name with different parameters, you can use `route.fullPath` instead of `route.name` as the `key`.

Comment: thank you, it works by wrapping it with such an html element

Comment: Although this ways works, however it keeps remount with every route request.

Comment: @AhmedShehab Isn't it the same when using just the `<component>` element unless you use Vue's [KeepAlive](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html)?

Comment: @EdisonArango KeepAlive is for caching, and apparently the transition triggers only onMounted event, if you elevated caching then it will mount only on first render.

Comment: @AhmedShehab My point is that your statement is not valid because just using the `<component>` will ALSO cause it to remount with every route change.

Comment: @EdisonArango I got your point,  and yes you are right, without keepAlive won't cache, my point is that wrapper with key around component prevents caching. hence it will remount every request. but same code without a key will work as expected with KeepAlive. try to cache it and check the result. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

I can't fully take credit for this one...but I was having a similar issue and the problem was I had multiple nodes in my view, and found this [guy's post on the Vue.js forums](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-3-transition-renders-non-element-root-node-that-cannot-be-animated/108965/4):

> Found my mistake too. Transition required a single root in components! Since Vue 3 no longer requires a single root node for components I thought this also applies to `transitions`.
> But it’s also logical. CSS requires a single root to which the transitions can refer.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when VUE tries to animate an empty template or one with 2 different items on the same level.

example:
this can't be animated

```
<template>
  <item1 />
  <item2 />
</template>
```

this can be animated

```
<template>
  <div>
    <item1 />
    <item2 />
  </div>
</template>
```

VUE can only animate one element at a time, so always define an element at the first level of the template, it can be a "div" or a "span", whatever, usually a div

Answer (score 2):

When toggling between elements that have the same tag name, you must tell Vue that they are distinct elements by giving them unique key attributes. Otherwise, Vue’s compiler will only replace the content of the element for efficiency. Even when technically unnecessary though, it’s considered good practice to always key multiple items within a  component.

```
<div>
  <router-link to="/"></router-link>
  <router-link to="/about"></router-link>
</div>
<router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
  <transition name="route" :key="route" mode="out-in">
    <component :is="Component" />
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

Comment: Hi Joye, since this is an old project from last year, I can't test your suggestion any more. Thanks very much however for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, it was a minor mistake, there was a character outside a html tag, directly after the  tag (comma).

```
<template>,
    <div>
      <div>
        <swiper>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
          <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
        </swiper>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

your dynamic component instance must have a root element.
in you example,'Swiper' and 'SwiperSlide' must have a root element!

Answer (score 1):

don't use `RouterView` in `component` parameter of the router. if you need to do that put it inside a root element

Answer (score 0):

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
 <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
  <!-- root element -->
  <div>
    <component :is="Component"></component>
  </div>
 </transition>
</router-view>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me using Nuxt3:

Parent page was:

```html
<template>
  <NuxtPage />
</template>
```

but should be also wrapped into a root node:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```

Otherwise I got a transition exception:

> Component inside `<Transition>` renders non-element root node that cannot be animated

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing like this and it works.

```
<template>
  <router-view v-slot="slotProps">
    <transition name="route" mode="out-in">
      <component :is="slotProps.Component"></component>
    </transition>
  </router-view>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'animate.css';
<template>
  <router-view #default="{Component}">
  <transition  :enter-active-class="`animate__animated animate__bounceIn`">
      <component :is="Component"></component>
  </transition>
 </router-view>
</template>
```

Comment: I have use have right