# [Vue warn]: Component inside <Transition> renders non-element root node that cannot be animated

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm getting the following error while giving transitions to routes,
when trying to get into router-view. Is it because of the div above?

```html
<template>
 <div id="nav">
</div>
<router-view v-slot="{Component}">
   <transition name="route" mode="out-in">
  <component :is="Component"></component>
  </transition>
</router-view>
</template>
<style>
.route-enter-from{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
.route-enter-active{
  transition: all .3s ease-out
}
.route-leave-to{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}
.route-leave-active{
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 – <Transition> renders non-element root node that cannot be animated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553121/vue-3-transition-renders-non-element-root-node-that-cannot-be-animated)

Answer (score 0):

Component template should contain exactly one root element. Put `router-view` in `#nav` div and you won't get the errors.

Comment: This is no longer true for vue3, you can have multiple root elements in the template.

Comment: Still not working brother

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it was Vue3 :)
Try to wrap your `component` inside `transition` with `div` and pass some `key` attribute to `div`, something like `route.name`

Comment: So this was also driving me mad since Vue3 allows multiple roots nodes in a template. *However*, if you want automatic transitions to be available to you in Nuxt between pages/views, you are then relegated to a one-root templating system _for those particular things_. Regular, non-animated, non-transitioning components can enjoy multiple root nodes just as you would in a standard Vue3 app.